# monit alert toggle rule

Tags: toggle, alert, monit

I would like to create monit alert rule, which acts like toggler.

Example: alert me once while host (icmp) become unreachable, and then alert me again one time, when when host is online. And work until monit daemon is alive.

```
check host tv with address tv.local
if failed icmp type echo count 5 with timeout 5 seconds
    then alert
else if passed
    then alert
```

That sample works each condition one at a time, and stops.

Thanks in advance.